# onclick i get null

Tags: android

ok i want my script to give me an answer on the first click but it takes me multiple clicks.

```
`package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EquationsActivity extends Activity {
    EditText field1;
    EditText field2;
    EditText field3;
    EditText field4;
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    TextView text3;
    String fnum;
    String snum;
    String tnum;
    String ftnum;
    String RAnswer;
    String Answer;
    String answer;
    double num7;
    double num8;
    double num9;
    double num10;
    double num5;
double num4;
double num3;
double num6;
double num1;
double num2;
double num11;
double num12;
double num13;
double num14;
double num15;
String num16;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    field1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf1);
    field2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf2);
    field3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf3);
    field4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf4);
    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            text1.setText(RAnswer);
            text2.setText(Answer);
            text3.setText(answer + "," + num16);
            fnum = field1.getText().toString();
            snum = field2.getText().toString();
            tnum = field3.getText().toString();
            ftnum = field4.getText().toString();
            RAnswer = Double.toString(num7);
            Answer = Double.toString(num11);
            answer = Double.toString(num14);
            num16 = Double.toString(num15);
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(fnum);
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(snum);
            num3 = Double.parseDouble(tnum);
            num4 = Double.parseDouble(ftnum);
            num5 = num2 - num1;
            num6 = num4 - num3;
            num7 = num6 / num5;

            num8 = Math.pow(num2-num1,2);
            num9 = Math.pow(num4-num3, 2);
            num10 = num8+num9;
            num11 = Math.sqrt(num10);

            num12 = num1+num2;
            num13 = num3+num4;
            num14 = num12/2;
            num15 = num13/2;
        }
});
```

}
}`

Comment: if the solution below was helpful, please consider marking at as "accepted."

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it takes you several clicks? There is some math in there that could potentially take some time. To debug, add this line at the beginning of the `onClick` method:

`Log.i("button", "onClick called");`

Now when you select the button, if this log message shows up in your LogCat, then the button is responding to the first click.

**Edit:**

Have you tried moving some of the method components around?

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        fnum = field1.getText().toString();
        snum = field2.getText().toString();
        tnum = field3.getText().toString();
        ftnum = field4.getText().toString();

        num1 = Double.parseDouble(fnum);
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(snum);
        num3 = Double.parseDouble(tnum);
        num4 = Double.parseDouble(ftnum);
        num5 = num2 - num1;
        num6 = num4 - num3;
        num7 = num6 / num5;

        num8 = Math.pow(num2-num1,2);
        num9 = Math.pow(num4-num3, 2);
        num10 = num8+num9;
        num11 = Math.sqrt(num10);

        num12 = num1+num2;
        num13 = num3+num4;
        num14 = num12/2;
        num15 = num13/2;

        RAnswer = Double.toString(num7);
        Answer = Double.toString(num11);
        answer = Double.toString(num14);
        num16 = Double.toString(num15);
        text1.setText(RAnswer);
        text2.setText(Answer);
        text3.setText(answer + "," + num16);
    }
```

Comment: i have tried that i and it still took me multiple clicks. and yes it is multiple clicks and not just waiting. the first click i get a message saying null,null on the 1st click. on the 2ndclick i get 0's then on the 3rd click i get the answers.

Comment: @daniel, `null,null` makes sense for the first click, because you never initialize `num16` or `answer`. `0,0` makes sense for the second click, because you are creating Strings from doubles that have not yet been initialized (so they default to 0). After that, since your variables have been initialized, the 3rd click works. So in the end, the button is being clicked, you just need to rethink the algorithm.

Comment: @daniel, try my suggested algorithm above.